# paypal integration error code 10002

Tags: paypal

I am using paypal directpayment, my account in paypal is already paypal pro. I already requested api username,password and signature and used it in my code but there is an error during execution. Please see below

```
 TIMESTAMP: 2012-06-12T14:33:04Z
 CORRELATIONID: 26e967f0870e1
 ACK:   Failure
 VERSION:   87.0
 BUILD: 2945183
 L_ERRORCODE0:  10002
 L_SHORTMESSAGE0:   Authentication/Authorization Failed
 L_LONGMESSAGE0:    You do not have permissions to make this API call
 L_SEVERITYCODE0:   Error
```

I am using this settings in live $API_Endpoint = 'https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp';

Does any one could help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Mostly it is to do with granting permissions to third party.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common error that you might get if you are using Paypal Express Checkout, or Paypal Website Payments Pro. This means that there is something wrong with your login information that you are using to authenticate the connection with Paypal.