# L_ERRORCODE0=10002 on sandbox account

Tags: curl, paypal

I am trying to make my first API call to my sandbox account using `curl` and it seems that I cannot get it right (following this [document](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/gs_PayPalPaymentsStandard/)).

I am trying to use PayPal Payments Standard, and my merchant account country is India, however I have tried US for sandbox too.

I am running the following code in `git bash` on windows (that has curl by default):

```
curl -s --insecure https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp -d 
"USER=m1_api1.***********.com&
 PWD=VMY***********XP5GM&
 SIGNATURE=AFcWxV******************************ao4d8dmUnoztmk&
 VERSION=1.0&METHOD=BMCreateButton&BUTTONCODE=HOSTED&BUTTONTYPE=DONATE"
```

*Note: I have formatted the code with line breaks for readability.*

But the response that I get is (after url decoding):

```
TIMESTAMP=2015-04-22T05:23:53Z&
CORRELATIONID=954d8fb6c250&
ACK=Failure&VERSION=1.0&
BUILD=15840636&L_ERRORCODE0=10002&
L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Authentication/Authorization Failed&
L_LONGMESSAGE0=You do not have permissions to make this API call&
L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error
```

*Note: I have formatted the code with line breaks for readability.*

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999291/paypal-integration-error-code-10002) stating that it might be for **incorrect username and password**, but  I am pretty sure that mine are correct.

Comment: try with VERSION=51.0

Comment: @SSH I tried, but still the same

Comment: Your credentials are wrong or you're including a space where you aren't. There really aren't any other reasons. Beside mixing up live vs sandbox endpoints, but per your example you do appear to be pointing to sandbox correctly. So just make sure you're using the right *sandbox* API credentials)

Comment: @Robert I have checked all the points, even I have reset the credentials retried, no help